# ImageView not visable in RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I am trying to make some changes in my RelativeLayout, and have stumble across some problem. At the top of my laout RelativeLayout called id/relativeLayout2 and a ImageView called id/img. Both the RelativeLayout  and the ImageView is located like above my screen, so it is not visable. I cant find out what im doing wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/bg4"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
android:gravity="left|center"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="30sp"/>





<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/img"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="180dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />



   <TextView
android:id="@+id/detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_below="@+id/img"
android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton3"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

<ScrollView
android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
android:layout_above="@+id/btn_BrowserLink"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"   
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"   
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</ScrollView>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_BrowserLink"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:text="@string/ticket"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton3"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: there's no android:orientation in RelativeLayout, just change it to LinearLayout if you want the Views to stack just horizontally/vertically, oh and you set the RelativeLayout containing ImageView above 'title' which not defined its position

Comment: Thank you. I will try to change it right away, and return to you.

Comment: i think you forgot to set layout position for the TextView @+id/title

Comment: hey here no need to change Linearlayout you can do it with Relative layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make below changes in your code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/bg4"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 >

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_above="@+id/title" //removethis line
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"//Add this line
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/img"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2" //add this line
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="2"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="30sp"/>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_below="@id/title"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton3"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

<ScrollView
android:layout_below="@+id/detail"
android:layout_above="@+id/btn_BrowserLink"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"   
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"   
android:fadingEdge="none"
android:scrollbars="none"
android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:paddingRight="5dp"
android:textSize="13sp"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</ScrollView>

<Button
android:id="@+id/btn_BrowserLink"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:paddingLeft="5dp"
android:text="@string/ticket"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton3"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
```

Comment: This did the job. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use seperate layout for each fields. Before starting define the page is horizontal or vertical. Then, we avoid these type of problems.

Answer (score 0):

In below layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
 </RelativeLayout>
```

just change the

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/title"
```

to

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
```